# How to make one flexbox move another inside of a container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with two flex-boxes inside of it.

1. The first flex-box is the header of my content box.
2. I have another flex-box that is the container for the content of the content box.

Whenever I shrink my browser, the header will overflow covering up some on my content in the content box.

Ideally, I would want the header to push the content down and not cover it up; however, I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <head>
  <style>
   body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
   }
   .wrapper{
    padding-top:60px;
    padding-left:60px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
   }
   .content-box{
    flex:1 0 30%;
    min-height:360px;

    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   }
   .header-wrapper{ 
    flex:1; 
    background-color:purple;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:5%;
    border-radius:2px;
    top: -15;
    min-height:75px;
    width:90%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   }
   .header{
   }
   .header-info{
   }
   .header p{ 
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 30;
    left: 12;
   }
   .header h1{ 
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: -15;
    left: 10;
   }
   .content-wrapper{
    margin-top:5%;
   }
   .content{    
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:5.5%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content-box">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <p>Subtext</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
    <p>First Content Content</p>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` from `.header-wrapper`.

To slightly position the title above the container, you can apply :

```
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

Comment: This fixes the problem that I have, but is it possible to place the title slightly above the container and still be dynamic?

Comment: Sure you can. Right now you are using `top:-15` to accomplish this. Instead, use `transform: translate(0, -50%);`. This should do the trick. You can increase or decrease the percentage.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the CSS to you need to shift the title up. If you want to control with `px` you can.  Just replace the `-50%` with `-15px`.